# Recursive typedef in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I'm using a typedef, and I'd like it to contains itself, but I've got compile errors, so maybe it's because I can't (or shouldn't). Is it?

Here's my typedef:

```
typedef Group = {
    var id: String;
    var ref: String;
    var rules: Array<String>;
    @:optional var groups: Array<Group>;
    @:optional var inputs: Array<Input>;
}
```

Then my code using it:

```
private inline function createGroup(xml: Fast): Group{
    if(xml.hasNode.Group){
        var groups = new Array<Group>();
        for(group in xml.nodes.Group)
            groups.push(createGroup(group));
        return {id: xml.att.id, ref: xml.att.ref, rules: rules, groups: groups};
    }
    else{
        var inputs = new Array<Input>();
        for(input in xml.elements)
            inputs.push(createInput(input));
        return {id: xml.att.id, ref: xml.att.ref, rules: rules, inputs: inputs};
    }
}
```

And I've got this error:

```
haxe: { rules : Array<String>, ref : String, inputs : Array<Input>, id : String } has no field groups
```

If I can't do that, I'll create a class, but that's kind of heavy for what I want to do. Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Looks like it compile if I create a var myGroup: Group = {...} just before the return and then return it. But why?

Comment: Recursive typedefs work fine in Haxe. There must be something hidden that caused the issue, but I cannot figure it out without a full example.

Comment: Here is the full class: http://pastebin.com/zkSZMMzC. Hope it helps

Comment: I mean a minimal example that can reproduce your problem, without any dependency of other lib or code. For example: http://try.haxe.org/#d3B28 (it does compile without any error)